# How to delete consecutive commas in an imported array in Mathematica?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I am importing an excel sheet into Mathematica. The result is a rectangular array. The array contains sequences of commas. Whenever a cell is empty in the Excel sheet consecutive commas appear in the imported array. How to get rid of them? So I am looking for a function $f$ such that for example

```
f({1,2,3,2,1,,,,6,5,4,3,,,,8})={1,2,3,2,1,6,5,4,3,8}
```

It doesn't look easy to me because it looks like reinventing the wheel.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I expect that those sequences of commas are actually separating empty strings (`""`), so you can replace them with e.g. `Nothing` and they will be spliced away. For instance, `{{1, "", 2}, {"", 2, 3}} /. "" -> Nothing` gives `{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}`.

Comment: Or try `{1, 2, , , 3} /. Null -> Nothing`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that right away.

Answer (score 6):

```
DeleteCases[{1, 2, 3, 2, 1, , , , 6, 5, 4, 3, , , , 8}, Null]
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove empty words (`""`) or `Null` by replacing by `Sequence[]`

```
In[1]:= list = {1,2,3,2,1,,,,6,5,4,3,,,,8};

In[2]:= list /. {Null -> Sequence[], "" -> Sequence[]}

Out[2]= {1,2,3,2,1,6,5,4,3,8}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f[L_List] := Map[If[# === Null, Nothing, #] &, L]
```